# Django ForeignKey with brackets: model cannot be resolved

Tags: django, migration

I need to use brackets to define my foreign key in Django. Unfortunately I get an error I can't fix..

```
raise ValueError('Related model %r cannot be resolved' % self.remote_field.model)
ValueError: Related model 'Deck' cannot be resolved
```

This is my model:

```
class DeckDevice(models.Model):
    deck = models.ForeignKey(
        "Deck", on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="deckdevice"
    )
    #somemorecode
```

my migration:

```
#somemoremigrations

migrations.CreateModel(
            name="DeckDevice",
            fields=[
                (
                    "id",
                    models.AutoField(
                        auto_created=True,
                        primary_key=True,
                        serialize=False,
                        verbose_name="ID",
                    ),
                ),
                ("start", models.DateTimeField()),
                ("end", models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)),
                (
                    "deck",
                    models.ForeignKey(
                        on_delete=django.db.models.deletion.CASCADE, to="film.Deck"
                    ),
                ),
            ],
        ),
```

Comment: `film` is in INSTALLED_APPS? Why would you not simply use "film.Deck" instead of using `to` argument?

Comment: I tried that, but didn't work

Comment: & yes it's in installed_apps

Comment: sorry, film.Deck worked (i did app.deck) -> THANKS!